# how to show ticks on bootstrap select box

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show the ticks when a property is selected, I am using django.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.buildings = kwargs.pop('buildings',None)
        super(CreateInvestigationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["building"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=self.buildings,
            required=False,
            widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={
                'class':'form-control selectpicker',
                'multiple data-actions-box':'true',
                'data-live-search':'true',
                'multiple title':'--- Please select ---',
                'multiple data-selected-text-format':'count > 2'
            }),
            label="Property:",
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `show-tick` to your class.

Try--

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.buildings = kwargs.pop('buildings',None)
    super(CreateInvestigationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["building"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=self.buildings,
        required=False,
        widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'class':'form-control show-tick selectpicker',
            'multiple data-actions-box':'true',
            'data-live-search':'true',
            'multiple title':'--- Please select ---',
            'multiple data-selected-text-format':'count > 2'
        }),
        label="Property:",
    )
```